# Is there a list of all English words (singular and plural) anywhere on the net?

Tags: resources

Does anyone know of a resource online that lists all known English words, including plural and singular forms of a word?

Comment: Impossible. There is no Academy that defines what "English words" are and, even if there was, words are being added and changed so often that, if one existed, it would be obsolete in an instant.

Comment: http://www.oed.com/ claim to be the definitive record of the English language.

Comment: @mgb I may well have to dedicate myself to finding a word they don't have now. They've got "spiflicate." This will be difficult...

Comment: @kitukwfyer - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0526724/quotes

Comment: @mgb Indeed...:)

Comment: First you need a definition of "word", and second a definition of what constitutes "English". Both are very problematic.

Comment: You want inflected forms of nouns (singular and plural) but not of verbs (past tense, past participle, present participle, 3rd person present) or adjectives (comparative, superlative)?

Answer (score 7):

There's probably no list of all words. But as a starting point you could check whether [Ispells](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wordlist/files/Ispell-EnWL/3.1.20/ispell-enwl-3.1.20.zip/download) (a spell-checker) input files are helpful.

For further resources see also
http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

There is no list of all known English words, because there are so many ways to identify what is a word and what is not a word, and so many reasons why a word may or may not be an English word. See this entertaining article in Slate summing up the problem:

http://www.slate.com/articles/life/the_good_word/2006/04/word_count.html

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aMain_Page)

Answer (score 1):

[WordByLetter.com](http://www.wordbyletter.com/) seems pretty comprehensive. If anything, it seems overly comprehensive, as in I'm not sure all of those are actual English words. But if lists of words is whats you wants, lists of words is whats it has.

Answer (score 0):

*[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)* is much more that just a list, but you may find it useful

> WordNet® is a large lexical database of English, developed under the direction of George A. Miller (Emeritus). Nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms (synsets), each expressing a distinct concept

Answer (score 0):

Try here: an amazing service. http://wordlist.aspell.net/
Lets you create your own lists, provides some pre-made ones, too.
(I'm constantly amazed at the amount of stuff available!)

Answer (score 0):

[How*j*say](http://howjsay.com/) might fulfil your needs.

It has 174,302 English words, and includes plurals, conjugated verbs, etc.

It also includes rare and archaic words - I can't find any omissions.

It also tells you both British and American pronunciations.